# How to call a generic function with parameter of associated type in Swift 3

Tags: swift, generics

Here's my sample code:

```
protocol P {

}

protocol B {

  associatedtype ID: P

}

class MyClass: B {
  enum ID: P {
    case one
    case two
  }
}

func process<T: B>(_ value: T.ID) {
  // do something
}

process(MyClass.ID.one) // Compile Error: cannot convert value of type 'MyClass.ID' to expected argument type '_.ID'
```

As you can see, I define a generic function with a parameter whose type is an **associated type** of the **generic type** **T**. How can I call this function? I want to use **MyClass.ID.one** as the argument, but the compiler gives the following warning:

```
cannot convert value of type 'MyClass.ID' to expected argument type '_.ID'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that Swift has a problem inferring `T` from the invocation by starting  from `MyClass.ID` being `T.ID` and backing into `MyClass` being `T`.

If you change your function to take an additional parameter of type `T`, the code compiles and runs fine:

```
func process<T: B>(_ value: T.ID, _ workaround : T) {
  // do something
}

let workaround = MyClass()
process(MyClass.ID.one, workaround)
```

Swift designers could approach this inference problem in two ways:

- Fix inference engine to allow for this use case, or
- Make it easier for the inference engine to figure out `T` by enforcing stricter rules on function signatures.

It appears that they decided on the second approach with Swift 4, because the original function fails to compile, issuing the following error:

> generic parameter `'T'` is not used in function signature

A better work-around is to pass the type instead of an instance, using Java-style approach:

```
func process<T: B>(_ value: T.ID, _ workaround: T.Type) {
  // do something
}
...
process(MyClass.ID.one, MyClass.self)
```

**Note:** The edit is based on very insightful [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566841/how-to-call-a-generic-function-with-parameter-of-associated-type-in-swift-3/44567301?noredirect=1#comment76125361_44567301) by [tesch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958214/tesch)

Comment: Yeah, I have also tried this. But I really don't need the extra argument : (

Comment: @ZhuShengqi Unfortunately, Swift does not let you specify the type of `T` explicitly either, like most other languages do (e.g. `process<MyClass>(MyClass.ID.one)` is illegal) so I think the best-case solution for this problem is for Apple to fix Swift compiler. To me, this is a shortcoming in compiler's inference engine.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are write. I'm just curious because without the last line, my code compiles. So the bug is that I define a function but cannot use it? Hope swift 4 would fix it.

Comment: Swift 4 probably won't fix this. Your function doesn't even compile in the Xcode 9 beta, it now gives the error `generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature`.

Comment: Regarding the workaround: you could pass the type directly as an argument `process<T: B>(_ value: T.ID, _ workaround: T.Type)` and then call the function like this `process(MyClass.ID.one, MyClass.self)`. This way you don't need a dummy instance.

Comment: @tesch Thank you very much for your comments! I like your work-around very much.

Comment: I just download Xcode 9 beta and find the same result :( Seems that I have no choice but add an additional argument just for type inference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

dasblinkenlight provides a good answer to why your current implementation doesn't work. If the decided resolution is to simply find another way to implement this function, then I would opt for a less hacky solution:

```
extension B {
    static func process(_ value: Self.ID) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

MyClass.process(.one)
```

This takes advantage of the more flexible type inference achievable via protocol extension `Self`.

Comment: It's some kind of API design. I have a singleton manager class that need to process the value, and I don't want the user to call a method on the class B.

Comment: Gotcha. I might leave the answer anyway in case it is useful for someone else reading this question.